# Should client and server have separate update lists on a website?

Tags: versioning

I have two separate programs that are only useful in a server-client architecture.  On the download site should i have the update list separate or together?

**Client**

```
Version 2.0
   -added the 2 to the version
   -became a better client

Version 1.1
   -added chat for client
   -client has a better design
```

**Server**

```
Version 2.0
   -added the 2 to the version
   -became a better server

Version 1.1
   -added chat for server
   -added disconnect all client button
```

**Together**

```
Version 2.0
   -added the 2 to the version
   -became a better server
   -became a better client

Version 1.1
   -added chat
   -added disconnect all clients button on server
   -client has a beter design
```

Which one would have a better *user experience*?

Comment: Assuming this is for expert users I would consider allowing them to chose. At the moment I don't know how long this list can get (if not very long then both together would be what *seems* to be the best option. Ultimately you need to find out from your users.

Comment: Well that brings up another question : how many versions long should these lists even be?

Comment: how long? What do your users need? What would you want in their places? Ask people who you're working with. What would they want? You need to ask - and accurately answer the question of "Who are our users?" "What do they need to do 'x'?"

Comment: I don't get it... Is it the change log that you are asking if should be - one for frontend and one for backend or wrap both in one?

Comment: I'm asking whether the change log should be separate for server and client or if it should be together.

Comment: is it possible that a client can be updated separately from the version - or will they always be updated in step? will most client users care about all of the server changes? perhaps maintain separate logs and allow users to filter between client/server/merged logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them option what are the users trying to update. Using that option as trigger to do the download. Make sure download file name indicates it's either server or client, optional add version as well.

It is also useful to have verifications included on it. Example, user uses client but is planning to update via server. There must be a notification that he is using client not server, and should he like proceed?